# File.getCanonicalFile doesn't fully resolve paths

Tags: java

Calling `getCanonicalFile` on a path such as `"/one/../../two"` returns `"/../two"`. Not all of the `".."` are resolved. In any other languages this would return `"/two"`. There are many potential problems with the Java behavior. Is there a Java method that behaves like other platforms? Do I have to do something wonky like call repeatedly until the return value stops changing?

Comment: Can you post a concrete example of your input and expected output? One which can preferably easily be created on a harddrive. I believe I know what you are asking for, I'll check once more information has been provided.

Comment: Try with `getAbsoluteFile()`

Comment: If you're using Java SE 7 or greater, consider to use the new NIO.2 File API instead.

Comment: I can't rely on having SE 7. Also, getAbsoluteFile doesn't resolve .. at all.

Comment: The behavior of `getCanonicalFile` is system dependent, and you're passing in an invalid path (`two` would be a sibling of `/`, which probably isn't really allowed).  On windows, using that path resolves as `C:\two`

Comment: You could always as a last resort write your own method that parses a string, if you can locate the base, then you can also locate the child or parent, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that 'one' is in the root directory, and that therefore "/one/../" resolves to the root and "/one/../../" and "/one/../../two" are undefined.

Comment: Except they're not undefined. Do "ls -a /" and look for "..". Or do "ls /..". It becomes a problem when working with a document root, where fully resolved paths should never point outside the document root.

Comment: It is possible that ls handles this situation, but it is still undefined, and possible that there is a definition for it.  I'm no unix expert, I don't know.  If there is a formal definition for it (across different unix versions?), and it is not handled correctly by getCanonicalPath(), then submit a bug to Oracle/Java.  But I wouldn't assume that it is defined just because ls produces output.

Comment: Yeah, this isn't some kind of special handling by ls. Also, it works correctly in any other language. I don't think there's a case to be made that the java API isn't broken. I was hoping there was some non-broken alternative, or a common pattern that is well-behaved, but apparently there isn't. Apparently the only thing to do is call repeatedly and exit when there are no '..' or when the value no longer changes.

Comment: Oh, so it works in C, JavaScript, FORTRAN, COBOL, Pascal, Forth, Lisp, PL/I, Scala, Ruby, Basic, C#, Visual Basic (6 and .NET), and Ada?  My, you've been busy.  All that and reading the ls source code too (in how many versions?)  Whether this is a bug or just something that some other programs/systems do and Java does not depends on the definition of the special characters used in the path, assuming one exists.  IF a definition exists and Java does not implement the definition, I would favor (you) filing a bug.  If there is no such definition, then there's nothing to say this is broken.

Comment: fstat is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
file.toURI().normalize().getPath();
```